# Show attribute under price WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

If I want to show a specific attribute under the price on the main product page, how do I do?

It is easy to add an attribute on a single product in WooCommerce, but to highlight it under the price on the main shop is the questions.

http://postimg.org/image/6myj5vy1t/

Answer (score 0):

You can use action hooks for that.  If you want it before the add to cart button.  You can use 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' or if you want it after the add to cart button, you can use 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'.  Have a look at the template file named content-product.php

Comment: How do I do that?

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
woocommerce_attribute(); ?>

Comment: SOLUTION:

<?php
   do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
   $product->list_attributes();
  ?>